# How to install themes in Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, themes, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React version 0.76.0, with React version 16.1.0. I am also using Webpack 3.8.1 and Babel. If it matters, I'm using NPM version 5.5.1.

I can't seem to find a way to use a theme for Semantic UI React. I have seen [some guides](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/366#issuecomment-237391443) directing me to `link` a stylesheet in my HTML, but this does not work.

Could someone please explain the steps to add a custom theme to Semantic UI React? Can you use any theme made for Semantic UI, or do they have to be compatible with React?